# how to top_n() returning all the rows in R

Tags: c

I'm trying to use top_n to get rows that contain the top 8 companies only. but when I use top_n, I get the data as the entire data frame.
When I try to replace it with a number, top_n works, but not when it is a string of type char.

#The top 8 companies

ts1$company <- as.symbol(ts1$company)

top_n(ts1, 5, !!sym(company))

ts1 %>% top_n(company, 8)

#The top 8 titles
ts1 %>% top_n(title, 8)

#The top 8 tag
ts1 %>% top_n(wt=tag, n=8)

Comment: How come this is tagged `C` but asks about `R`? I know some `C` but no `R`. How can I help you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Top_n is my data frame, company is the columns. When I execute top_n(top_company, 5, ! !sym(company)), R shows Can't convert a character vector to a symbol. I think this is probably because the company column is a string and not a number.
I'd like to know how to run                                 
top_n(top_company, 5, ! !sym(company))  
or Top %>% top_n(wt=tag, n=8)

Comment: @WangWayne To have better success asking questions here, make sure you use the correct tag(s). Since you've used the `C` tag, the question only attracts people with knowledge about `C`. When they see that the question is about a different language, `R`, they most probably just go away (unless they happen to know that programming language too). You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73966196/edit) your question to remove the faulty tag and put the correct tag in there instead. You can also add the information you've provided in the comments to the question where that information belongs